# What's wrong with this Jena Ontology API code

Tags: jena, owl

I am trying to print the list of individuals in my ontology. My code for printing out the classes are working fine. However, the following code to print the list of Individuals in my ontology is giving me this error:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.ConversionException: Cannot convert node http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2014/9/Ontology123.owl#Abc to Individual
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.IndividualImpl$1.wrap(IndividualImpl.java:61)
```

My java code (with Jena API) is below:

```
public class MynewClass

{
static String filename ="./src/resources/myfile.owl";
static OntModel model;
static OntModel model1;
static OntClass a1;

public static void main (String args[])


{  
  try
{

     File file = new File(filename); 
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_TRANS_INF, null );    

    model.read(reader,null);     

    Iterator indv = model.listIndividuals();
    while (indv.hasNext())
     { 
     Individual indiv = (Individual) indv.next();
     System.out.println(indiv);  
     }

    }
 catch (Exception e)

 {
    e.printStackTrace();

  }
}
```

thanks in advance for any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your individual has also another type - could it be that it is being punned? Is there another entity with the same IRI in your ontology?

Comment: thanks for your answer, it could be the case, i will test this code with another consistent ontology to check the point you mentioned.